# How to get document title in a workflow (2013) developped with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, visual-studio

I have got a 2013 workflow (developped with Visual Studio 2012) on a document library.  It starts when a new document is created.

How can I get the document title to use it in my workflow?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `LookupSPListItem` and `GetDynamicValueProperties` actions to retrieve list item values.

1. Add the `LookupSPListItem` action to  your sequence.
2. In the `LookupSPListItem` action, specify `currentitem` and `currentlist` for your item/list values.
3. Click the `Get Properties` link to generate a `GetDynamicValueProperties` action.
4. Specify the source as list item of your list. Then specify the values you wish to retrieve (Title, in your case), as well as the variables to store the values in.

You can find visuals and more details [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620173/Step-by-Step-Approach-to-Create-a-Visual-Studio-Sh).

Comment: Thanks for your response but it's exactly what I've done.
And title is empty. Maybe because the list use content type?

Comment: Do a REST query on your library.  With the info returned, get the internal name of the field containing the value you need, and use that.

Comment: Can you explain me REST query and how to do this on workflow?
Thx

Comment: It wouldn't be done in a workflow.  Just enter the following in your web browser: `<site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<yourlibrary>')/Items`.  If using IE, you may need to [disable feed reading](http://www.jaysmith.us/post/Turn-Off-Feed-Read-Preview-to-Show-XML-in-Internet-Explorer.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand because I need to get the title in my workflow to use it (for example send an email with the title).

Comment: This would make sure you've got the right field. Post what you are doing in the WF.

Comment: OK the internal name I have to get is linkFileNameNoMenu but in my workflow this field is empty

Comment: Use `Title`, as that contains the value (again, REST would've told you this...)